# Postman file uploading: the file path became missing when I close the request tab

Tags: api, file-upload, postman, postman-collection-runner

I'm uploading files through PUT request and put my file as a `Binary` into the `Body` request:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXuMa.png

The problem is that the file path became missing once I close the request tab and I try to run through `Runner`, so this makes it impossible to run it through `Runner`.

Here's the screencast of what I mean: http://take.ms/ptLCT

Is there a way to save the file path inside the request body?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a [long standing issue with postman](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4320) that is still not resolved. It seems you can get around it by [using newman instead](http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/09/21/run-collections-with-file-uploads-using-newman/) (postman commandline runner). Alternatively check out [Insomnia REST client](https://github.com/getinsomnia/insomnia) instead, which seems to support this.